# Asset not making its way to production (link to example included)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, asset-pipeline

Any ideas on why some css that works locally isn't making it into the asset pipeline on production?

Specifically the top nav bar over the graph should toggle between different graphs at this link. http://cappedin.com/posts?event_id=226894&league_id=1

It works locally! Classic "it works on my computer" but when I push to Heroku I can't toggle between the tabs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that when pushing to Heroku it would compress my javascript files. This did not happen locally. Locally there were errors in the console but none that affected specific feature.

When compressed the javascript just totally did not work thus making my application.js file that was compressed useless. Make sure you have no console errors in javascript! Use Google Chrome to check your javascript console!